# Highcharts logarithmic computational algorithms

Tags: logging, highcharts

When the type "logarithmic" is set to xAxis,scale change "20K,40K,100K,200K,400K",Can you help me explain highcharts logarithmic algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic axes are often used when you have a very wide range of data values with lots at the lower end, but a few values much bigger.

Imagine if you are trying to plot the following values:

```
1
2
3
10
1000
10000
```

If the y axis values are spaced evenly, the first few datapoints would all look the same, as they are tiny compared to the max.

If you give more space to smaller values, and less to large values, you can show more detail at the smaller end of the scale.

It's probably easier just to show this in action. This jsfiddle shows the same data plotted normally and then logarithmically : http://jsfiddle.net/qSStj/